# Centering multiple elements in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have four `UIButtons` in a parent view, next to each other. The leftmost and the rightmost one will always be smashed into the sides of the parent view, but I'm not sure how I should approach positioning the middle two buttons with constraints.

What I want it to look like:

```
______________________

[b1]  [b2]  [b3]  [b4]
______________________
```

With regular constraints on `x` and `y` I'm able to place `b1` and `b2` on the right place, but `b2` and `b3` requires some magic.
By using constraints on them, telling them to stick to each side, it would look like this in landscape(or on bigger screens):

```
______________________________

[b1]  [b2]          [b3]  [b4]
______________________________
```

Without equal spacing. What I need is something like the 'flexible space' which is used for UIBarButton's, but in a regular view. As I can't find anything like that, I'm guessing there's some constraint-magic I need to understand.

I COULD make the buttons big enough so that they are all constrained together (so `b2` and `b3` are touching, and they all have equal width), but I don't want that. I guess a solution could be to create four ´container´-views in those sizes (big enough to touch each other) and simply place each button in the center of each UIView. But is that really necessary? Feels like such a waste..

Answer (score 0):

You could add UIViews where the three flexible spaces need to be:

```
–––––––––––––––––––––––––
[b1] * [b2] * [b3] * [b4]
–––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

Then for each of the spacer views (denoted by *), add constraints such that the trailing and leading spaces are 0 and give them a constant height. Finally, add a another constraint to make all of their widths equal. That way, the spacing between each button will always be equal regardless of the width of the screen. Then you can just make the spacer views transparent so they don't appear in your layout.